# Enabling both local and remote connections to a mysql server on linux (ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, connections, remote

Is there any way to enable both remote connections and connections via "localhost" to a mysql server. I tried adding both

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
bind-address = externalIP
```

but it just used the one later in the file

Is this something that is possible or will I have to just use one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Which will allow both. "If the address is 0.0.0.0, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 interfaces. "

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address